# GraphQL Search Query INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: jss, graphql

**The Query:**

```
{
  search(fieldsEqual:[
    {name:"_fullpath", value:"/sitecore/content/*" }
   ]) {
    results {
      totalCount
      }
  }
}
```

**The Result:**

```
  "data": {
    "search": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Error trying to resolve search.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "search"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INVALID_OPERATION"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Config Settings:**

```
<queries hint="raw:AddQuery">
                  <!-- enable querying on items via this API -->
                  <query name="item" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.ItemQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
                  <query name="sites" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.SiteQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
                  <query name="templates" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.TemplatesQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
                  <query name="search" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.SearchQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
                </queries>
```

How come my basic search gives an error? Is there something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the configuration you supposed is really used?

- First be sure you deployed the config to all Sitecore servers,
  the `jss deploy config`, is only deploying the config to the CM server, not the CD if you have separated servers.
- With the url `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` you can display the [compiled configuration](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/view-configuration-changes.html), make sure the search is in your GraphQL endpoint, There may be old or other config files that will destroy your search configuration.
- Be sure you use the endpoint, with

```
<GraphQL>
 <endpoints>
  <yourendpointGraphQLEndpoint>
   <schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
    <queries hint="raw:AddQuery">
     <query name="search" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.SearchQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
```